# Emails are getting spammed/blocked by outlook if sender and recipient email id are same send via send grid

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

I'm using Send grid for sending emails to the user.

When I'm trying to send a email from abc@outlook.com to abc@outlook.com
via send grid then its either coming into spam or not received.

Where as i send a mail from abc@gmail.com to abc@gmail.com
it worked fine and getting into inbox.

or sending from abc@gmail.com to abc@outlook.com
worked fine as well

```
SMTPServerName - smtp.sendgrid.net
SMTPPort - 587
```

What could be the possible reason